# problem when get data from Async method, and add it to another async method in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, asynchronous

in my flutter application i have an API, and this API need an endpoint which is (:id), so this (Id) i received it from shared preference, because i add it to shared preference when the user make a (login), it is work fine, and i can received this (id), but the problem i cannot get data from API i think because get data from shared preference take some time (async) to get (id), i could get the data from API just when make (reload) to my app,, this is my code:

```
String userId, userToken;

  getTokenAndId() {
    Pref.getId().then((uid) => {userId = uid});
    Pref.getToken().then((token) => {userToken = token});
  }


  getOrders() async {
    var res = await http.get("http://192.168.43.106:3000/order/user/${userId}");
    if(res.statusCode == 200){
      var jsonObject = json.decode(res.body);
      return jsonObject['result'];
    }
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    getTokenAndId();
    getOrders();
    super.initState();
  }
```

how can i solve this problem please? thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var result;
getOrders(){
    Pref.getId().then(userId){
      http.get("http://192.168.43.106:3000/order/user/${userId}").then(res){
        if(res.statusCode == 200){
          var jsonObject = json.decode(res.body);
           setState((){this.result = jsonObject['result'];});
        }
      };
    }
  }

@override
  void initState() { 
    getOrders();
    super.initState();
  }

 @override  
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
   //for example
   if(this.result==null)
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
    else
    return Text(this.result.firstName)
 }
```

Comment: thank you for your replied, but unfortunately , still same problem

Comment: Make sure that these methods are "Future, async", " Pref.getId() and Pref.getToken()" , It should work fine, I'm sure , Add some breakpoints in your code

Comment: yes bro, it has already worked, when just i make reload it is work find as i mentioned, the problem i think just because it take a time because (async) so the id initially will be null, so cannot get data from api.... i think the problem here, but i don't know how can i fix it...

Comment: Now I understand what you mean, Usually, we use some method to show Progress Bar, But you need to use Stream, After all, I'm going to update the answer to your old way, it's working ok

Comment: i don't know what is the problem? i try it, and also edit it, but still same problem, i have to reload then data displayed>

Comment: i used (print) to check if id returned or not, i add it before (http.get) and it is return the id without any problem!!! but i don't know why?

Comment: good, what the return this code : if(res.statusCode == 200) , add try catch , then add breakpoint in catch area , and retest

Comment: this (res.statusCode ) return 200, everything look good!

Comment: So you don't need to return a value, just rebuild the page by setState() method, Like this :  if(res.statusCode == 200){
          var jsonObject = json.decode(res.body);
        setState((){result = jsonObject['result'];});
        }

Comment: and use the result variable in build method

Comment: it is work, just like this, like your idea, but without promises, maybe the problem was from using promises:
getOrders() async{

  userId = await Pref.getId();
      var res = await http.get(
          "http://192.168.43.106:3000/order/user/${userId}");
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonObject = json.decode(res.body);
        return jsonObject['result'];
      }
}
thank you for your effort...